# How to make Apache Camel Restlet producer to ignore SSL hostname verification

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x, restlet

I'm using the Restlet Component of Apache Camel and I have a route which connects to an https URL exposed with a self-signed certificate.

Using `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` I solved the problem related to the untrusted certificate, but at this point I'm stuck on the hostname verification.

Here is an excerpt from the stacktrace, where you can see that the **Apache Camel Restlet Component** uses the **Restlet** library which finally uses **Apache Http Client**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <192.168.1.1> != <localhost>
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:231)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:152)
    ...
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:347)
    ...
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.process(RestletProducer.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
```

The question is the following: is there a way to disable the hostname verification on Restlet or on Apache Http Client using a system property or some kind of static method ?

Comment: Can you provide code snippet related to your producer configuration and ssl?